# How can input fields be rearranged using drag and drop in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a form where I have question and multiple answers. I would like to rearrange my answer options by dragging and dropping. I have tried using html5's drag and drop feature https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp but the I'm not clear on the jquery part as I'm new to it. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery only allows you to get have simpler javascript.
Also, with jquery UI you can get actions like that (draggable, droppable, sortable).[jquery UI link](https://jqueryui.com/)